# Finding the path to file using application startuppath in a windows form

Tags: windows, forms, filepath

Hi every one I am trying to access a file in certain folder in my windows form app, but I keep getting the error "could not find a part of the path: C:....e.t.c".
here is my code:

```
string doc = Application.StartupPath + @"\filefolder\pin-card02.docx";
```

please what is wrong with this piece of code?
I have seen some explanations but nothing tells me how to direct my program to a certain file in a folder...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There's probably nothing wrong with this piece of code, most likely this file is not set as content of your application and is not getting copied to the output directory, if this is part of a visual studio solution, check that pin-card02.docx has "copy to output directory" set to "Always" or "Copy if newer" in the .doc's properties, if it's not part of the solution, you may need to include it and set the property.

If this doesn't help, you'll need to provide more information on the problem.